# ionic replace tabs and footer for new view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

My codepen link : http://codepen.io/gauravcoder/pen/JGZjrb
i have made ionic pages with tabs which has tabs and tops and buttons at footer .

Now i want when footer button is clicked , top tabs must disappear and top header bar with page title should show with back arrow to navigate to back page.

i tried to do but could not figure out.

Below is attached image

**check image : http://goo.gl/gPgz8e**

Code:

```js
angular.module('ionicApp.controllers', [])
.controller('Tab1Ctrl', function($scope){

})
.controller('Tab2Ctrl', function($scope){

})
.controller('Tab3Ctrl', function($scope){

});
```

```css
.btn-footer .button { margin: 0; }
.btn-footer .row { padding: 0; }
.btn-footer .col { padding: 0 5px; }
.img-box img { max-width: 100%; }
.p0 { padding: 0; }
.tabs-top-my .tab-nav.tabs { top: 0; }
.my-content-tabs > .row { height: 100%; }
.my-content-tabs .col-25,.my-content-tabs .col-20 { position:relative;}
.img-box {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
#maincontainer > div.scroll{padding-left:10px;}

.my-imgs-scroll { height: 100%; overflow:hidden !important; overflow-y:scroll !important; }
ion-scroll > div.scroll > img{ border-bottom:1px solid #eee;}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title>Ionic page</title>
<link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="//fabricjs.com/lib/fabric_with_gestures.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="HomeTabCtrl">


<ion-side-menus>
  <ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-nav-view> </ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="right">
   <div class="list">
   <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#"><i class="icon ion-email"></i> Check mail</a>
   <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#"> <i class="icon ion-chatbubble-working"></i>Call Ma</a> 
   <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#"> <i class="icon ion-mic-a"></i> Record album</a> 
   <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#"> <i class="icon ion-person-stalker"></i> Friends</a>
   </div>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>  

<ion-footer-bar  class="bar-footer btn-footer bar-light">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button  button-block button-positive"> View cart Page </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button  button-block button-calm"> View checkout page </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-footer-bar>


<script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-positive tabs-top tabs-top-my tabs-icon-only" animation="fade-in-out">

        <ion-tab title="tab1" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/tab1">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab1-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="tab2" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/tab2">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab2-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="tab3" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="tabs.tab3">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab3-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="tab4" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="tabs.tab4">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab4-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="tab5" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="tabs.tab5">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab5-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="tab6" icon="ion-android-apps" ng-click="toggleRightSideMenu()"  ui-sref="tabs.tab6">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab6-tab"></ion-nav-view>

        </ion-tab>

      </ion-tabs>
    </script> 
<script id="templates/tab1.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="tab1">
        <div class="my-content-tabs scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header has-footer has-tabs-mytop">
            <div class="row p0">
                <div class="col col-25 p0">
                  <div class="img-box">
                    <ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="y" class="my-imgs-scroll" id="maincontainer">

                    </ion-scroll>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-50" id="canvascontainer">
                                        tab 1
                </div>
                <div class="col col-25 p0">
                  <div class="img-box">
                    <ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="y" class="my-imgs-scroll" id="maincontainer1">

                    </ion-scroll>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

      </ion-view>
</script> 

<script id="templates/tab2.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="tab2">
      <div class="my-content-tabs scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header has-footer has-tabs-mytop">
          <div class="row p0">
            <div class="col col-25 p0">
              <div class="img-box">
                <ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="y" class="my-imgs-scroll" id="maincontainer">
                </ion-scroll>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-50" id="canvascontainer">
                                        tab 2
            </div>
            <div class="col col-25 p0">
              <div class="img-box">
                <ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="y" class="my-imgs-scroll" id="maincontainer1">
                </ion-scroll>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>

    </ion-view>
</script> 
<script id="templates/tab3.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="tab3">
       <div class="my-content-tabs scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header has-footer has-tabs-mytop">
            <div class="row p0">
            <div class="col col-25 p0">
              <div class="img-box">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-50">                    <canvas id="canvas3"></canvas> </div>
            <div class="col col-25 p0">
              <div class="img-box">
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </ion-view>
</script> 
<script id="templates/tab4.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="tab4">
       <div class="my-content-tabs scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header has-footer has-tabs-mytop">
            <div class="row p0">
            <div class="col col-25 p0">
              <div class="img-box">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-50"> Coming Soon   </div>
            <div class="col col-25 p0">
              <div class="img-box">
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </ion-view>
</script> 
<script id="templates/tab5.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="tab5">
       <div class="my-content-tabs scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header has-footer has-tabs-mytop">
            <div class="row p0">
            <div class="col col-25 p0">
            <div class="img-box">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-50"> Coming Soon   </div>
            <div class="col col-25 p0">
            <div class="img-box">
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </ion-view>
</script> 
<script id="templates/tab6.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="tab6">
       <div class="my-content-tabs scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header has-footer has-tabs-mytop">
        <div class="row p0">
        <div class="col col-25 p0">
        <div class="img-box">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-50"> Coming Soon   </div>
        <div class="col col-25 p0">
        <div class="img-box">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </ion-view>
</script> 
<script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Tab Nav Stack">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p><img src="http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script> 
<script>
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ionicApp.controllers']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tabs.tab1', {
      url: "/tab1",
      views: {
        'tab1-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/tab1.html",
          controller: 'Tab1Ctrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.tab2', {
      url: "/tab2",
      views: {
        'tab2-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/tab2.html",
  controller: 'Tab2Ctrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.tab3', {
      url: "/tab3",
      views: {
        'tab3-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/tab3.html",
          controller:'Tab3Ctrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.tab4', {
      url: "/tab4",
      views: {
        'tab4-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/tab4.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.tab5', {
      url: "/tab5",
      views: {
        'tab5-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/tab5.html"
        }
      }
    })
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/tab1");

})
.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
  $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };
  $scope.toggleRightSideMenu = function() {
      console.log('rigth open')
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleRight();
  };
  console.log('HomeTabCtrl');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it using modal windows:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
   scope: $scope,
   animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function(modal) {
   $scope.modal = modal;
});
$scope.openModal = function() {
  $scope.modal.show();
};
$scope.closeModal = function() {
  $scope.modal.hide();
};
//Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  $scope.modal.remove();
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjVeOR

Or just with another state:

```
<div class="col">
  <button class="button  button-block button-positive"
   ui-sref='next'>View cart Page </button>
</div>
```

...

```
.state('next', {
  url: "/next",
  templateUrl: "templates/next.html",
  controller: "NextController"
})
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeEWGq

**Update**:
I made a color in a header, but I can't make animation works...

Comment: thanks for it i do not want to use modal i would prefer state http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeEWGq , can u tell how can i add smooth trasition on back press and cart click

Comment: hey can u tell why header bars are without color